# reshape data frame via multiindex

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I created this example data

```
pd.DataFrame.from_items([(0,['a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2']), (1,['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2']), (2,['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'])])
    0   1  2
0  a1  b1  m
1  a1  b1  n
2  a2  b2  o
3  a2  b2  p
```

I want to 'reduce' this data frame into having the index for the unique values in column '0' and then as a column returns an array of the values in column '2'. 
e.g.

```
       '2'
Index 
a1    [m,n]
a2    [o,p]
```

I need this to be a data frame as a result, as I want to join the resulting data frame onto another one. Both of them are 'fairly' big (18mio rows). 
I tried using stack but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I tried using pivot tables, but then the values out of col '2' are in the header, instead of being used as values. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `apply`, last convert to `Series` [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
print (df.groupby(0)[2].apply(list))
0
a1    [m, n]
a2    [o, p]
Name: 2, dtype: object

print (df.groupby(0)[2].apply(list).to_frame())
         2
0         
a1  [m, n]
a2  [o, p]
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.groupby(0)[2].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_frame())
         2
0         
a1  [m, n]
a2  [o, p]
```

---

If need output as [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([(0,['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2']), 
                              (1,['b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2']),
                              (2,['m', 'n', 'm', 'p'])])
print (df)
    0   1  2
0  a1  b1  m
1  a1  b1  n
2  a1  b2  m
3  a2  b2  p

print (df.groupby(0)[2].apply(list).to_frame())
            2
0            
a1  [m, n, m]
a2        [p]

print (df.groupby(0)[2].unique().to_frame())
         2
0         
a1  [m, n]
a2     [p]
```

Comment: Thank you, where can I find a comprehensive overview of how to deal with dataframes and group by? Any help is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Glad can help you. And I think [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) is perfect.